# Как получилось, что документ "Вид на жительство" называется словом "вид"?

Tags: этимология, жаргон, канцеляризмы

Каков смысл этого названия? Кто смотрит этот "вид"? Зачем кому-то "смотреть на жительство"? Как пришло в голову так назвать документ, разрешающий проживание?

UPD. Если [искать через Гугл Ngramm Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=25&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%3B%2Cc0), среди первых находится документ ["Положеніе о видах на жительство со включеніем остальных дѣйствующих паспортных узаконеній и правительственных разъясненій"](https://books.google.ru/books?id=qdJLAAAAYAAJ) от 1900 года, но к сожалению я не вижу там способа его почитать. Наверняка из способов употребления этого словосочетания в том документе что-то бы прояснилось... Но увы..

Comment: Ответ на вопрос: https://otvet.mail.ru/question/66805311

Comment: К сожалению, там нет ответа, там лишь небольшая историческая справка с констатацией такого использования.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исходя из того, что (как это видно по приведёным здесь ссылкам) вид на жительство требовался человеку лишь для предъявления различного рода постовым и контроллирующим перемещения и деятельность граждан чиновникам, я склонен счесть что это именно для них, для контроллирующих перемещение официальных лиц, этот документ был единственным достоверным *видом* (способом посмотреть!) на официальное место жительства контроллируемого ими человека.

То есть название документа могло пойти из фраз-требований типа "Предьяви-ка, проходимецъ, мне вид на своё жительство!"

Answer (score 1):

Не хочется повторять за другими, но по сути добавить к уже сказанному нечего.
*Слово **вид** приобрело значение "разрешение (на жительство)" в результате развития значения "планы, расчеты".*

> 4. только мн.: виды, -ов. Планы, расчёты, намерения относительно чего-л. 
>      Виды на будущее. Виды на урожай. ◊ Вид на жительство.

БТС Кузнецова.
http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4&all=x

Насколько понимаю, вас в этом объяснении не устраивает только то, что оно не отвечает на вопрос, как появилось то самое значение "расчеты", посредством которого и развилось интересующее "вид на жительство". Больше то тут и придраться-то не к чему.

Но и это сомнение, если дело в нем, надумано. В русском языке морф "вид" и построенный на нем глагол видеть имеет широкий спектр значений: понимать, представлять, мечтать, грезить.

Сравните, например, с английским I see - я вижу (в значении "понимаю")

Вот примеры такого значения глагола "видеть" (из нацкорпуса).

> Не исключено, что он видел себя знаменитым французским писателем,
>   блестящим стилистом, быть может даже одним из сорока бессмертных,
>   прикрывшим свою лысину шёлковой шапочкой академика, вроде Анатоля
>   Франса. [В. П. Катаев. Алмазный мой венец (1975-1977)]
>
> Здесь он видел себя наследником и продолжателем дела своего отца, по
>   праву считающегося основоположником современной кибернетики. [Николай
>   Богданов. «С природою одною он жизнию дышал...» // «Знание - сила»,
>   2010]

Отсюда уже совсем недалеко до "вид" в значении воплощения, реализвции такой мечты или планов. Если очень дотошно подходить, то "вид на жительство" можно трактовать как  документ, дающий право видеть (себя и другим) законно проживающим там-то и там-то.

По поводу версии Людмилы. Она интересная по части влияние французского, но есть вопрос.

*Людмила, а можно ли назвать калькой данный случай? Даже если принять версию о влиянии французского, тут имеет место просто прямой перевод. Или вы (вслед за автором ?) не считаете это значение слово "вид" родственным всем остальным? .Это было бы странно, поскольку морф "видеть" явно прослеживается.*

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77944/discussion-on-answer-by--------).

Comment: Ага, а чат быстро дохнет, и того обсуждения уже не достать. А оно было информативным. Не делайте так больше, пожалуйста!

Comment: @Nashev пройдите в чат, там все ваши комментарии остались. Комментарии предназначены для уточнения какой-либо информации в ответе, а не для дискуссий.

Comment: При переходе по ссылке в чат я попадаю на страницу Page not found, поверх которой написано что чатиться можно с репутацией от 20

Comment: Заработал немножко репутации, рубеж 20 преодолел, но по вашим ссылкам на чаты по-прежнему вижу Page not found

Comment: @Nashev у меня чат доступен.Больше ничем не могу помочь. Попробуйте задайте этот вопрос на мете.

Answer (score 1):

Термин вид на жительство можно объяснить процессом калькирования (семантического копирования) в конце 18 - начале 19 века.

Видеть - общеславянское слово, но имеет соответствия в других и.-е. языках. Ему родственны  лат. videre (видеть) , visere (рассматривать). Получается, вид и виза - синонимы - просмотренные документы, завизированные, т.е. на них есть подпись ответственного лица, разрешение. Вид и виза - разрешение на въезд в страну и проживание в ней.

**Виза**- заимствование из французского, восходящее к латинскому visa, буквально означающее "просмотренные (документы)", причастия прошедшего времени от videre – "смотреть, видеть". 
 http://enc-dic.com/krylov/Viza-1582.html

**Вид** на жительство — документ, удостоверяющий личность иностранного гражданина или лица без гражданства и подтверждающий получение им разрешения на постоянное проживание в государстве пребывания.

**Вид** на работу — документ, удостоверяющий личность иностранного гражданина или лица без гражданства и подтверждающий получение им разрешения на трудовую деятельность в государстве пребывания.

Вид на работу заменился разрешением на работу, а на жительство так и остался видом, в отдельных значениях ему синоним паспорт, а для крестьян и мещан ещё и  плакат - тоже устаревшее слово, употреблявшееся до 1917 года.

Так что вид - не от видеть, а от просмотреть (рассмотреть), это уже издержки калькирования, там важен смысл, а не внешний вид слова.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77945/discussion-on-answer-by--------).

Comment: Людмила, я предусмотрительно сохранил свой конкретный вопрос (по поводу термина "калькирование") в тексте своего ответа.

Answer (score 0):

**Из словаря:**  ВИД, 4. только мн.: виды,  **Планы, расчёты, намерения** относительно чего-л. Виды на будущее. Виды на урожай.

**Вид на жительство.** 1. В России до 1917 г.: документ, удостоверяющий личность получателя и членов его семьи и дававший право на проживание где-л. (выдавался вместо паспорта). -2. Документ, выдаваемый иностранцам в дополнение к паспорту в случае длительного пребывания в данной стране.

Таки образом, вид на жительство можно представить как заявленное **намерение** на жительство,  получившее **разрешение** властей.